# How to add an icon to the right hand side of the MacOS menu bar in Electron?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, menubar

I am a fan of the [bitbar project](https://github.com/matryer/bitbar) that enables you on MacOS to add menu bar items to the right side of the menu bar like this:

[image]

Those icons persist even when the focus is on another window and can give the user live information about services running in the background.

I am building some apps with the Electron Framework and was thinking of wrapping bitbar into my applications, but that seems a little bit over engineered.

Is there a way to add an icon to this side of the menu bar? If not: Does anybody know a good example of such an implementation that includes an installer?

Electron's [documentation of the Menu bar](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu) doe not indicate it. But maybe I overlooked something or there are other implementations of this MacOS only feature?

Comment: I haven't tried it but this l[ink](https://steemit.com/education/@ryanbaer/getting-started-with-electron-a-basic-menubar-app-part-1) might help.

Comment: thank you so much, No Grabbing! This brought me to the right search term: "electron tray" which led me to https://electronjs.org/docs/api/tray. i will test and report here. but this really looks promising!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user [No Grabbing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840992/no-grabbing) pointed me precisely in the right direction! Thank you!

I was looking with the wrong search parameters: "Tray" seems to be the term i was missing:

Electron actually does already provide an API for that and after testing it i can say: it works out of the box: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/tray

Comment: only caviat in comparison with bitbars features: electrons Tray requires an image path on instanciation. As a fix I used a 1 transparent pixel png and .setTitle() to only have a text based menu item.